# How to manually install grub with two hard disks

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, uefi

I have two disks built in my Asus rog laptop. One 1tb gpt HDD with one important partition and one 128 gpt SSD.

I installed windows 10 EFI on my HDD and then did nothing and went straight to install Ubuntu 17.10.

I did install it and it worked very well. And note that grub got installed automatically containing windows bootloader. For some reason I had to this: I deleted every partition of the HDD (except the important one which contains personal files) and did nothing else. When I restarted the laptop, there was nothing to boot from. Apparently, grub had to be installed on the HDD in order to recognize windows. But I am 100% sure that my ubuntu is ok but there's just no bootloader to point to it.

Now I have installed windows on the unallocated partition on HDD.

My question is: How should I install grub manually from ubuntu live so that it can recognize both windows and ubuntu?

There are answers to this but I'm not sure if they'll work for me because I have OSs on two separate disks.

Comment: which of the two disk contains the new windows 10 and which contains ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

To sum it all up:

- Installed Windows on your HDD, with Windows' Bootloader.
- Installed Ubuntu on SSD, Grub gets installed on HDD (Along with Windows' Bootloader)
- Formatted the HDD keeping only one private partition, so Windows and both Windows' Bootloader and Grub are gone.
- Installed Windows again, with Window's Bootloader.

So now you're only missing Grub which needs to be installed on your HDD,
This question as you said yourself has been asked many times, but just because you wanted to make sure which one is gonna work out for you, I'll link you to [one of them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).